# Explode multiple columns SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can we explode multiple array column in Spark? I have a dataframe with 5 stringified array columns and I want to explode on all 5 columns. Showing example with 3 columns for the sake of simplicity.

If I have the following input row:

```
col1                  col2                              col3
["b_val1","b_val2"]   ["at_val1","at_val2","at_val3"]   ["male","female"]
```

I want to explode on all 3 array columns, so the output should look like:

```
b_val1   at_val1   male
b_val1   at_val1   female
b_val2   at_val1   male
b_val2   at_val1   female
b_val1   at_val2   male
b_val1   at_val2   female
b_val2   at_val2   male
b_val2   at_val2   female
b_val1   at_val3   male
b_val1   at_val3   female
b_val2   at_val3   male
b_val2   at_val3   female
```

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
timestamp,
explode(from_json(brandList, 'array<string>')) AS brand,
explode(from_json(articleTypeList, 'array<string>')) AS articleTypeList,
explode(from_json(gender, 'array<string>')) AS gender,
explode(from_json(masterCategoryList, 'array<string>')) AS masterCategoryList,
explode(from_json(subCategoryList, 'array<string>')) AS subCategoryList,
isLandingPage,
...
from table
```

but this is not allowed nd I get the following error - `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Only one generator allowed per select clause but found 5: explode(jsontostructs(brandList)), explode(jsontostructs(articleTypeList)), explode(jsontostructs(gender)), explode(jsontostructs(masterCategoryList)), explode(jsontostructs(subCategoryList));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use withColumn to get the required output.

Let's create one sample dataframe with 3 columns of arraytype and perform explode operation:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val rdd=spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(List(Row(Array(1,2,3),Array("a","b","c"),Array("1a","1b","1c"))))

val schema=new StructType().add("arraycolumn1",ArrayType(IntegerType)).add("arraycolumn2",ArrayType(StringType)).add("arraycolumn3",ArrayType(StringType))

var df=spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)

df.show(5,false)

   +------------+------------+------------+                                        
   |arraycolumn1|arraycolumn2|arraycolumn3|
   +------------+------------+------------+
   |[1, 2, 3]   |[a, b, c]   |[1a, 1b, 1c]|
   +------------+------------+------------+

val explodedDF=df.withColumn("column1",explode('arraycolumn1)).withColumn("column2",explode('arraycolumn2)).withColumn("column3",explode('arraycolumn3))

  explodedDF.select('column1,'column2,'column3).show(5,false)

      +-------+-------+-------+
      |column1|column2|column3| 
      +-------+-------+-------+
      |1      |a      |1a     |
      |1      |a      |1b     |
      |1      |a      |1c     |
      |1      |b      |1a     |
      |1      |b      |1b     |
      +-------+-------+-------+
      only showing top 5 rows
```

Let's do the above steps with less lines of code

```
  var exploded=df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df,column)=>df.withColumn(column,explode(col(column))))

 exploded.select(df.columns.map(col(_)):_*).show(false)
```

Using spark-sql

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("arrayTable")

 spark.sql("""
  select column1,column2,column3 from arraytable
  LATERAL VIEW explode(arraycolumn1) as column1
  LATERAL VIEW explode(arraycolumn2) as column2
  LATERAL VIEW explode(arraycolumn3) as column3""").show
```

Comment: Any way to do this in SQL? Don't have the flexibility to write scala code

Comment: We can do that using LATERAL VIEW, Edited the post, please have a look.

Comment: How to do this in Pyspark ?